# Show that each term of a composition of formal power series $A(B(q))$ is computed in finitely many steps if $b_0 = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, formal-power-series

I'm doing an online course on Enumerative Combinatorics. In the chapter on formal power series and nonlinear recurrence relations, we start off by looking at compositions of formal power series $A(B(q))$ expressed as:

$$\sum_{n\geq0} a_{n}(B(q))^n$$

with $a_n \in A(q)$.

An exercise proposed by the instructor is to determine why computing each term of the above sum takes finitely many steps if $b_{0} \in B(Q) = 0$.

I had a little think and it doesn't seem to me why this would be possible if $b_0 = 0$. Let's take the second term of $A(B(q))$, $a_1B(q)$, and assume $b_0 \in B(q)$ is $0$.

We have $(a_1b_0=0) + a_1b_1q + a_1b_2q^2 + \dots$.

Is this last expression finite somehow?

Comment: I believe you're misinterpreting the question: I interpret it as showing that for each fixed $k$, the coefficient of $q^k$ in the composition can be computed in finitely many steps.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah, that's possible, okay but even so, supposing $b_0 \neq 0$, that would contribute just one extra non-zero term to the expression, won't it? What would make those other terms not computable in finitely many steps because of it?

Comment: @user16555 Then with $B(x)=1+x$ and all $a_n=1$, whatt is the coefficient of $x^3$ - or *any* coefficient of the composition?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, by $x^3$ do you mean $(B(x))^3$? And with $a_n = 1$, then the coefficient of any $(B(x))^n$ will be just 1, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A(B(q))=\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nq^n$, and say you want to compute $c_n$. The key idea is that the only contributions to $c_n$ come from the terms $$a_0+a_1 (B(q))^1+a_2(B(q))^2+\dots a_n (B(q))^n.$$
Indeed, for any $m>n$, the term $(B(q))^m$ will only have powers of $q$ which are greater than $n$. Therefore, you just need to extract the coefficient of $q^n$ in each of the above terms, which it should be clear can be done in finitely many steps.

We require $b_0=0$, because otherwise the composition is not a well defined power series. For example, let $A(q)=1/(1-q)=1+q+q^2+\dots$, and let $B(q)=1$. Then we would have $A(B(q))=\frac10=1+1+1+\dots$, which is impossible.

Comment: Ah, the last paragraph contextualises why $b_0 = 0$, thank you. Regarding the bit about extracting the coefficient of $q^n$, for any $n$, that would be $n$ steps, right, since there are $n$ coefficients?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a step. For example, to compute $[q^n](B(q))^2$, you need to do $b_0b_n+b_1b_{n-1}+\dots+b_nb_0$, which takes $O(n)$ arithmetic operations. For $[q^n](B(q))^3$, one way is to compute the sum of $b_ib_jb_k$, where $(i,j,k)$ ranges over all $\mathbb N$-triples summing to $n$.

Comment: Just to clarify your notation, $[q^n](B(q))^n$ is the coefficient extraction operator, right? If so, perfect, that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, $[q^n]$ is the coefficient extraction operator.